# Neo4j-3.0.0-M03 fails to start server neither from /etc/init.d nor by hand

Tags: neo4j

Trying to get Neo4j-3.0.0-M03 running on Ubuntu Server 15.10. Created user neo4j, extracted distribution there and installed a symlink. Also I want to use neo4j wrapper command as a /etc/init.d script and use it like every other script, say: service neo4j start

What I get:

```
root@n:/home/neo4j/server/bin# ls -la /etc/init.d/neo4j 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan 28 10:24 /etc/init.d/neo4j -> /home/neo4j/server/bin/neo4j

root@n:/home/neo4j/server/bin# service neo4j status
● neo4j.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
root@n:/home/neo4j/server/bin# service neo4j start
Failed to start neo4j.service: Unit neo4j.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
root@n:/home/neo4j/server/bin# java -version
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)

root@n:/home/neo4j/server/bin# /home/neo4j/server/bin/neo4j status
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
ERROR! Neo4j cannot be started using java version . 
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 8 or OpenJDK(TM) to run Neo4j Server.
* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.
root@n:/home/neo4j/server/bin# /home/neo4j/server/bin/neo4j start
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
ERROR! Neo4j cannot be started using java version . 
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 8 or OpenJDK(TM) to run Neo4j Server.
* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.
root@n:/home/neo4j/server/bin#
```

Seems like two separate problems:

1. neo4j wrapper fails to understand Java version
2. neo4j wrapper is not suitable to be used as /etc/init.d script right now (this is a pity and I suppose it is intended to be used as that?)

WBR, Andrii

Comment: neo4j-common.sh uses a variable version_command which itself works, but when feeding it's output to awk you need add `2>&1` explicitly so it feeds it's output to awk as intended, not to console. It works than. And one should write init.d script by hand, in case you don't want to use .deb package (I don't and I have solid reasons for that).

Comment: Hello @stesin. I've just fixed this problem in the Neo4j codebase. You should know that M03 has not been released yet and is likely to have bugs. If you want to try out the bleeding edge I recommend using the released M02 which you can download from our website.

That script is indeed not intended to be used as a SysV init script. If you can't use the Debian package then it should be fairly easy to write your own -- you can always use ours for inspiration (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.0/packaging/installer-linux/installer-debian/src/main/resources/common/neo4j-service).

Comment: I *do* know that M03 in't out yet, thank you. I'd suggest reviving the good old deprecated neo4j-installer.sh due to the very simple reason: I am not satisfied with .deb package. Tried it once and discovered that .deb spreads all the stuff all around the filesystem, this is inconvenient. Also .deb all of a sudden upgraded my 2.2.whatever to 2.3 which crashed some features of my project. I'd prefer a more classic UNIX logic: have everything live inside neo4j $HOME directory with ~neo4j/server being a symlink to whatever version I do have at the moment.

Comment: or at the very list to have .deb version-separated so if I have say 2.3.* .deb installed, it will not upgrade to 3.0.* and 3.0.* won't upgrade to 3.1.* silently

Comment: and thank you for providing us with https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.0/packaging/installer-linux/installer-debian/src/main/resources/common/neo4j-service I'll use it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on the .deb package.

Spreading stuff around the filesystem is normal behaviour for .deb packages (and those of other package managers on Linux). They follow the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. This isn't something that we're likely to change in our package.

However the problem of unexpected upgrades is something that we're conscious of. We are considering introducing packages with versions in the names just as you suggest.

Comment: "packages with versions in the names" - that will be perfectly satisfactory as for me; as soon as things will settle this way, I'll obviously switch to the package installation. One more important suggestion: package should not overwrite configuration files; i.e. "stock" neo4j-wrapper.conf which comes with package, should go into neo4j-wrapper.conf.dist (and *.dist files are to be upgraded); if we are doing fresh install, *.conf.dist files should be **copied** into respective *.conf but if I already have my customized neo4j-wrapper.conf file - please leave it untouched! Thanks in advance :)